# Configure SASS loader with VUE CLI 3 (replace Koala-app)

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vue-cli, koala-app

I'm developing with vue.js and vue cli 3. Currently I handle my CSS styles with SASS and compile them with [Koala-app](http://koala-app.com/). At the moment I am still using it because it is very easy to configure the main.scss and their respective files, and then compile it with autoprefix, in compressed format and with source map to another folder with the name styles.css, I keep the following structure:

[image]

I need to replace koala with NPM SASS Loader, how do I replicate this same configuration with VUE CLI 3? The information for the webpack should be added in vue.config.js? Or where? and what would be the parameters to achieve the same effect?